# How to Join multiple table without NULL value in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I need help with query:
There are 3 tables named:

```
 1. comments (fields: id, uacc_id_fk , comment)
             (values: 1, 5, my comment)
             (values:2, 10, hi im fine)

 2. dogowner_profile (fields: uacc_id_fk,dpro_name,dpro_image)
                     (values:5,Jones,Jones.jpg)


 3. doglover_profile (fields:uacc_id_fk,dlpro_name,dlpro_image)
                     (values:10,jeeva,jeeva.jpg)
```

I need result like:

```
(fields: uacc_id_fk , comment , name , image)
(values: 5, my comment, jones, jones.jpg)
(values: 10, hi i'm Fine, jeeva, jeeva.jpg)
```

But the output I am getting now is like:

The query I used here is:

```
  SELECT comments . * 
       , dpro_name AS Name
       , dlpro_name AS Name
       , dpro_image AS Image
       , dlpro_image AS Image
    FROM comments
    LEFT 
    JOIN dogowner_profile 
      ON comments.uacc_id_fk = dogowner_profile.dpro_uacc_id_fk
    LEFT 
    JOIN doglover_profile 
      ON comments.uacc_id_fk = doglover_profile.dlpro_uacc_id_fk
```

But the result I got here is:

```
(fields:id,uacc_id_fk,comment,name,name,image,image)
(values:1,5, my comment,jones,NULL,jones.jpg,NULL)
(values:2,10,hi i'm Fine,NULL,jeeva,NULL,jeeva.jpg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple columns that *might* contain data or *might* be `NULL`, and you want to find the first non-`NULL` one, just use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    comments.*,
    COALESCE(dpro_name, dlpro_name) AS Name,
    COALESCE(dpro_image, dlpro_image) AS Image
 FROM
     comments
     LEFT JOIN dogowner_profile ON
         comments.uacc_id_fk = dogowner_profile.dpro_uacc_id_fk
     LEFT JOIN doglover_profile ON
         comments.uacc_id_fk = doglover_profile.dlpro_uacc_id_fk;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help,Mr underscore_d.  That really helped. Meanwhile, why don't u put real name in your profile :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Please note that for larger queries, perhaps the later edited answer by Venkatesh could be faster - or at least easier to write. I have not tested to compare the speeds.

Answer (score 3):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
       SELECT comments . uacc_id_fk  ,comments.comment , dpro_name AS Name,dpro_image AS Image
       FROM    comments
      JOIN dogowner_profile ON comments.uacc_id_fk = dogowner_profile.dpro_uacc_id_fk

    Union   

        SELECT comments . uacc_id_fk  ,comments.comment , dlpro_name AS Name,dlpro_image AS Image
        FROM    comments
       JOIN doglover_profile ON comments.uacc_id_fk = doglover_profile.dlpro_uacc_id_fk`
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this query will reduces the execution speed ?

Comment: I think it will not reduce the execution speed.

Comment: This will _increase_ the number of rows containing unwanted nulls.

Comment: Yes , I got repeated unwanted nulls.

Comment: Then please test my alternative suggested solution above.

Comment: OK, your update using implicit `INNER JOIN` instead of the original `LEFT` should produce the same output as my suggestion - for this particular data set. I don't know which would perform better.